# Composite component with ReactiveFormsModule - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a composite component (a component that contains other "input" components). However, I can't make it work due to `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` issue, that is thrown when a component is being initialized. Here's a demo of the issue that I managed to reproduce:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvsqye

Any ideas what is going on? It starts to work when I replace `required` component with simple `input` inside `composite`, so I guess this has something to do with how they communicate.

Thanks